# Is every involution (on an orientable manifold) orientation reversing?

Tags: manifolds, orientation, involutions

I am sorry if this comes accros as a low effort question, but i couldn't find any reliable source and i guess it's true but i would appreciate any confirmation.

Let $M$ be a orientable $m$-Manifold. Let $\alpha: M \to M$ be an involution, that is $\alpha(\alpha(x)) = x$. 
The standard examples of involutions i am aware of involve $\alpha_1(x) = -x$ and $\alpha_2(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Which both qualify as orientation reversing functions.

I could imagine the given question to be true if every involution is a composition of either $a_1$ or $a_2$. However, i dont know whether this is true in general.

Highly appreciating any hint!

**Additional question:** Does the question i'm asking depend on whether the involution is fix point free?

Comment: In $\Bbb R^2n$, the central reflection $x\mapsto -x$ is orientation preserving.

Comment: Yes, on odd-dimensional spheres the antipodal map is orientation-preserving.

Comment: thanks for your comments. What about $x \mapsto x^{-1}$. Does this qualify as an involution, that is always orientation reversing?